# Apache Camel - Invoking http or rest calls (filtered through Shiro Security)

Tags: rest, apache-camel, shiro

Need some suggestions to find out if its possible in Camel for the below scenario.

We are trying use Apache Camel for integration testing of a web application. Application has to accessed through rest service calls. Each Application requests is filtered through shiro security. When I make a restful call or a http call to this application, I need to set up the necessary shiro authentication information in the header and make sure the camel request is processed successfully.  Is there a way to do this in camel - "invoking a http or rest calls to access the application whose requests are secured by apache shiro" ? I see Camel has a shiro security component which is more like either authorizing camel routes or defining the security for the camel routes and I dont see I can use them for this purpose?

I did try setting up the shiro authentication tokens in the header in different possible ways (For eg: using Exchange's Authentication property) but it doesnt work. Any suggestions please?

**UPDATES:**
Shiro maintains its own session and looks for userId and his/her Permissions (referred to as Shiro Subject) to make sure its an authenticated and authorized request. Whenever we send a request to a Shiro secured application, it filters the request, validate the request to find out if its authorized to access to application functions and then allow us in.If the user information is not available in the Shiro session, it will take you to the login screen. Our web application has exposed the functionalities as rest services.Is it feasible in Camel to make a call to such an application which is embedded with Apache Shiro security? Basically I am should mock the Shiro subject and set in the HTTP header to make it look like a Shiro Authenticated request.

I tried making http calls with Shiro Authentication token set up in the exchange headers. But its failing. Is this possible in Camel or am I going in the wrong direction? Any suggestion or help in this regard is very much appreciated. Below is a subset of code I have been playing around with.

// wrap it in a Subject

```
Subject subjectUnderTest = new Subject.Builder(getSecurityManager())
        .principals(new SimplePrincipalCollection("Username", "RealmName")).authenticated(true).buildSubject();    

MockEndpoint OutEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock.out");

OutEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

Endpoint InEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("direct.in");


Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();

headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "GET");

headers.put(Exchange.AUTHENTICATION, subjectUnderTest);

template.sendBodyAndHeaders(InEndpoint, "test body", headers);
```

Thanks Viggy

Comment: Generally you can set any header you like on the Camel exchange and that header will be sent as an HTTP header with your request. What would the exact requirements for authentication via Shiro be?

Comment: I have added my updates on what I was trying to do in our application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use below code to set up user name and password. Set CamelContext with these config.

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.setAuthMethod(AuthMethod.Basic);
config.setAuthUsername("donald");
config.setAuthPassword("duck");
HttpComponent http = context.getComponent("http", HttpComponent.class);
http.setHttpConfiguration(config);
```